# Cannot add app in itunes connect

Tags: app-store-connect

While adding a new app on itunes connect I'm getting

> Try again. If the problem persists, contact us

Without any other details. I have tried different computers / browsers. If I open the chrome console I see that there is an internal server error on the http request.

Comment: It looks like Apple are having problems with this service. After searching for this exact same issue, I have noticed that a lot of people are asking questions in forums over the last 2 days. Past-week Google search is always helpful: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=itunes+connect+Try+again.+If+the+problem+persists,+contact+us&tbs=qdr:w

Comment: Are you from Israel? guessing by the name... Since I am from there and I got this problem too :\

Answer (score 3):

I called Apple iTunes provider support - US  : 0014089744897 about this. They told me that they are aware of the problem, having had alot of calls about this today, and are looking at it

Comment: Excellent news. No one likes to feel they are the only ones not getting submissions in. Thanks for the confirmation +1

Answer (score 1):

When all else fails, contact Apple Developer Support.

- https://developer.apple.com/support/

You might not be doing anything wrong and need them to see what's happening on the other end of the submissions process.  I would back off your submission attempts exponentially and contact support when you are waiting 8 hours before your next upload attempt.

While you are waiting for a response (or better before escalating to support), double check the validation steps in Xcode Archive organizer

- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/UploadingYourApptoiTunesConnect/UploadingYourApptoiTunesConnect.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH36-SW2

From there, I would use Xcode to try pushing the update to iTunes connect instead of using the web interface.

Comment: Yup already did that. Thanks.
It's amazing to me that such an expensive service works so bad.

Comment: @uri I don't have high expectations for $10 a month service that handles many thousands of app submissions daily.  If you are losing money you can always buy/use a paid support incident and in effect pay more for individual attention.